# Shell Script -x Flag Meaning

Tags: shell, if-statement, sh, flags

I have a #!/bin/sh script that has the following line:

```
if [ ! -x "$TEST_SLAPD" ]
```

`$TEST_SLAPD` is the full path to a .bat file.

I am wondering what the `-x` flag means in the context of that `if` statement?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`if` just checks for result of command following it. `[` is not (at least not always) an operator, it's small utility called 'test'.

From its documentation:

```
-x file
                             True if file exists and is  exe-
                             cutable.   True  indicates  only
                             that the execute flag is on.  If
                             file  is a directory, true indi-
                             cates that file can be searched.
```

(and yes, `!` is obviously negation)

For similar evualation flags, documentation is available here:  http://illumos.org/man/1/test

Answer (score 3):

The `! -x` conditional means the file or directory doesn't have the executable bit set for the current user. The help is a little less clear about the fact that it applies to directories too, but it says:

```
$ help test | fgrep -- '-x'
      -x FILE        True if the file is executable by you.
```

Comment: If that is returning false and the file is definitely there is it likely a permissions issue with the shell script trying to execute the .bat file?

Comment: @Baxter Yes. That's why -r and -x are often a more useful than just testing for a file's existence with -f.